# Tsql query help

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can someone help me with a tsql query please. I am look at the dbo.backuphistory table in msdb. I want to find the average duration for each database and then total time of all databases. Can someone provide an example?

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
SELECT database_name, 
AVG(DATEdiff(SECOND,backup_start_date,backup_finish_date)) "AVG duration (Sec)", 
SUM(DATEdiff(SECOND,backup_start_date,backup_finish_date)) "Sum duration (Sec)", 
COUNT(1) as "Nb backup",
CASE WHEN type ='L' THEN 'Log' WHEN type='D' THEN 'Full' WHEN type ='i' THEN'Diff' END as "Backup Type"
FROM msdb..backupset
GROUP BY database_name, type
ORDER BY database_name, type
```

Comment: Yeah something like that. What if i want a specific date? And what does the nbbackup do in your query?

Comment: nbbackup is the number of backup that was done... I taught that just the sum of the duration, without the number of backup done, didn't mean that much.
If you want for a specific date, just inclure a where clause with something like : Where backup_start_date between '2020-04-01 00:00:00' and '2020-04-01 23:59:59'.

Comment: That should do it thanks